# How to search for an id within a class, the id changes everytime the page reloads

Tags: javascript

```js
document.getElementByClassName('_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP')
```

The id within my class changes every time I reload the page. I need to find the id within the class f as shown below stays constant in the id as shown below with some ids. The class stays constant, so how do I find the new id within my class everytime. I would like to do this using Javascript RAW

f19c49e0e618e18
f8ca3372aa0bd8
f5c32cc227cf38

Comment: I removed the jquery tag sorry for troubling you young sir.

Comment: the end is here, you cannot hack facebook. stop wasting your time with it

Comment: can you try to answer my question? I am not trying to hack facebook xD

Comment: How the OP seeks to use the information is not really our concern. Perhaps its about building a chrome extension or something, no clue. But the question is common one, and easily answered IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// We're going to get all the elements and force them into an array,
//  rather than a nodeList. That's what the [... and ] are doing to
//  our selector.
let myElements = [...document.getElementsByClassName('_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP')],
    arrayOfIds =  [];

// We can now use each member of myElements in a forEach. Within that,
//  the current member is called 'element'. So we can see its ID, and do
//  whatever we need to do with that.
myElements.forEach(function (element){ arrayOfIds.push(element.id);} );

console.log(arrayOfIds)
```

Comment: document.getElementByClassName(...) is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Comment: make that `document.getElementsByClassName(...)` (notice the 's' on 'Elements') or `document.querySelector('._2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP');`

Comment: Execution of script 'New Userscript' failed! document.querySelector(...) is not a function or its return value is not iterable @snowmonkey

Comment: I'm an idiot -- querySelector is not the iterable. `document.querySelectorAll(...)` returns an iterable list.Sorry about that.

Comment: and it doesn't recognize the space in class names. So use just one part of that string.

Comment: Thanks a bunch my dude that works [...document.querySelectorAll('class')]

Comment: Do you have discord I would love to talk code with you.

Comment: I've got a huge array now how do I find the id i'm looking for?

Comment: your help is very appreciated sorry to bug you.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what criteria you're using to select an element, I really don't know which ID you're looking for.